# facebook wp7 login button not working

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

On my WP7 app, I am trying to authenticate with Facebook using OAuth 2.0 and can get to the login screen of facebook. When I enter the username and password and try to click Login, the button doesn't get clicked for some reason.  (This is in the emulator).  I am not sure why I am not able to click the Login button.

Here is the link that I navigate to for facebook login page to show up
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&display=touch&scope=publish_stream  - where the {0}, {1} are substituted accordingly before navigating.

Thanks,
Pratik

Comment: Has anyone else run into this issue? When I change the display to wap it, I get to a different login screen and click the Login button, but it won't work when the display is touch.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured it out.

The browser control has a property IsScriptEnabled which seems like it is false by default.  Set that property to true and I can click the button.  This is pretty strange because I was able to click other button for Cancel even before setting this property.

At least, for anyone else who runs into this issue, please try setting IsScriptEnabled = true and give it a shot.

Pratik